# Error after update

Tags: update-manager, repository

**Hello** I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed grub-customizer this 2 commands First:- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer` and Second:- `sudo apt install grub-customizer` and after installing, it works perfectly but everytime when I type this command to do update via terminal the command `sudo apt update` gives this output :-

```
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't know what and why is this but want to solve it. Thankyou.

Comment: I installed the grub-customizer but skipped adding the ppa.

Comment: How to do that can you please assist me because I have already installed it@David

Comment: If I remember I installed it from the programmers site and know I do not remember the exact URL.

Comment: Also after a grub update are the settings reverted to original and do we need to do the changes we have done again?@David

Comment: I did have to redo the order of the OS in grub after a version update they went back to default.

Comment: Ok so do I remove the repository ppa from the software updator list from the software update app.@David

Comment: If it gives an error yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed grub customizer from the instruction on the authors site here. https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer From that page it reads

How to install:

- Ubuntu 19.10 or newer: Just run `sudo apt install grub-customizer` - exists in [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=grub-customizer)

Comment: I removed the grub-customizer ppa  ```main code``` and ```source code``` from other software section in software & updates app but what if I have to update the app how will I come to know that the app has a update released? @David

Comment: Look at the link on the right side it has been years since an update. So check back there once in a long while.

Comment: It's probably safe to say that program is suffering permanent bitrot now...

Comment: What's bitrot? @ThomasWard

Comment: @PiyushMhatre it means that it is unmaintained and likely to have issues as time goes forth - just like wood rots over time, so does unmaintained programs and code.